# Most concise String.Replace to mask a password

Tags: vb.net, string

Let's say I have the following string:

```
"/encryption:aes128 /password:<PASSWORDHERE> /log:log.txt"
```

I need to write this to a log file but the password needs to be masked (replaced with asterisks for example).

I can do this easily with `String.IndexOf` and `String.Replace` in a few lines of code but I'm interested in seeing how others would implement this so that the code is as short and concise as possible. A one line replace function would be best.

My goal here is to see/learn some new techniques of combining string functions.

**Note that I am not interested in using a RegEx.**

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Discussion Board](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550/140505) - asking for how others would do something is not right for the SE Q&A format.

Comment: I will never understand the idea of wanting to artificially do something in one line of code. The examples I see that make their writers so proud are almost always incomprehensible.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: It's the scientific curiosity in the most cases, I hope. :)

Comment: RegEx is ideal for this kind of task, why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Contrary to what Andrew Barber thinks, this works fine and is perfectly comprehensible assuming an even basic ability to read code. You might want to crack open a textbook Andy boy.

Assuming:

```
strArgs = "/encryption:aes128 /password:<PASSWORDHERE> /log:log.txt"
```

Then:

```
strArgs = strArgs.Replace(strArgs.Substring(strArgs.IndexOf("/password:") + 10, strArgs.IndexOf(" /log:log.txt") - strArgs.IndexOf("/password:") - 10), "********")
```

Answer (score 2):

I will not show you a one-liner since it would be incomprehensible as Andrew has already noted.

You insisted on a non-regex approach:

```
Dim input As String = "/encryption:aes128 /password:htzrj584372 /log:log.txt"
Dim pwdStart As Integer = input.IndexOf("password:")
If pwdStart <> -1 Then
    Dim pwdEnd As Integer = input.IndexOf(" /log:", pwdStart)
    If pwdEnd <> -1 Then
        pwdStart += "password:".Length
        Dim pwdLength = pwdEnd - pwdStart
        Dim pwd = input.Substring(pwdStart, pwdLength)
        Dim logText = input.Replace("password:" & pwd, "password:*****")
    End If
End If
```

Note that it would fail if the passsword itself would contain `/log:`.
Only the part before would be masked since i don't know the actual length of the password.